# Boto3: How find existing S3 bucket by the name?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've tried this way:

```
resource = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_URL)
resource.buckets.filter(name='somename')
```

But it returns all existing buckets. I've tried to use `filter(Filter=<list of dicts for filtering>)` with the same result.
I've read documentation, tried to google it, still no result.

Comment: Just check the creation date of a bucket by if resource.Bucket(bucket_name).creation_date if it returns none then it does not exist.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi but why filter does not filter? I feel frustrated.

Comment: try this: `bucket_iterator = s3.buckets.filter(name='somename')` `print(list(bucket_iterator))`

Comment: @saranjeetsingh  no offense, but have you read my post?

Comment: @ringo What do you mean by "how find existing"? Are you wanting to know whether a bucket exists? What if it exists in a different account than your AWS account? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if they do exist in someone's else, will they be in my `resource.buckets.all()`?
If so, I find it strange, but okay. If they will be there, I want to be able to find it using `filter` method.

Comment: `resource.buckets.all()` will only list the buckets in the AWS Account associated with the credentials you use. What do you mean by "find it using the filter method"? What do you mean by "find"? Why can't you just access it by name? Are you wanting to use it, list its contents, confirm that it exists, or something else?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
`resource.bucket` has the method `filter`. I expect it could be used to filter out all objects from the collection which do not satisfy some criteria. For now, it seems it just returns the same objects.
And I ask do I do something wrong? What I have to do to filter this collection by name of a bucket or to receive empty collection or an error if there's no such bucket.

Comment: The documentation does not specify what filters can be used for that command. Why do you wish to filter by name? If you know the name of the bucket, you can address it directly. Please explain the objective you are wanting to achieve (rather than _how_ to achieve it), we can try to recommend a suitable method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to check if a bucket with the given name exists in that collection. Why this method exists at all if it does nothing?

Comment: But why do you want to know if it exists "within that collection"? Why specifically do you want to use filter? Is it just because you are interested in what the `filter` function does, or are you trying to achieve a specific task? As to why something might exist if it does nothing, you'd have to ask the people who wrote boto3, since that is a function specifically implemented in boto3 rather than in AWS.  You can probably ask in the GitHub project: https://github.com/boto/boto3

Comment: @JohnRotenstein as I said before: I need to check if bucket with given exists within collection returned `resource.buckets`.
I've mentioned boto3 in the title and tags not just for fun. I am explicitly asking about boto3 related method. 
It is okay if I never receive an answer to my question. 
But it looks strange to me when people recommend me to run the code pieces which are exactly the same as in my starting post or when they try to tell me that I don't need that I am asking for. 
I faced strange behavior of a function in Boto3 and all I need is to know why it happens.

Comment: If you have an actual business requirement that you want to achieve, I would be happy to help. This might involve using a different command, so it would be worth knowing the actual goal you are trying to achieve (eg test if a bucket is in my account, test if a bucket is in somebody else's account, test if you have permissions to access a bucket, etc). However if you are just asking about the behaviour of that command "out of interest", then you possibly won't receive an answer from contributors.

Comment: Yes, I have this by requirement. We have some workflow for the resources we use.
Maybe, from S3 perspective it looks kinda weird, but from our, it's not.
Currently I do it like this:

        for some_bucket in buckets.all():
            if some_bucket.name == name:
                bucket = some_bucket
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{name} does not exist')
It's fine but could be better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference a bucket, use:

```py
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('foo')
```

Comment: Will it raise an error if a bucket with name "foo"　does not exist?

Comment: Not immediately, no. Why do you ask?